# How can the type of variable be set in grails templates?

Tags: grails, groovy, intellij-idea

For the parameters passed in the `model` attribute of the `render` method to a grails template, how can I specify the type of the parameters in the templates?

I am using grails 2.4.4. This is merely required for autocomplete features in Idea and is not at all related to the file templates of Intellij Idea.

For example, if I have the following tag definition

```
def markRead = { attrs ->
    out << render(
            template: "/templates/commons/post/markRead",
            model: [
                    user: attrs.user,
                    post: attrs.post
            ]
    )
}
```

And in template I have below (WIP so not complete)

```
<g:if test="${user != null}">

</g:if>
```

I want to do something inside the `if`. But as this was passed through the model there is no type information associated with it and hence there is no autocomplete present. The logical solution seems to be specifying the type somewhere. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by `templates`?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore In the view part of grails there are gsp whose name start with underscore. They are called templates. These are not file templates of Intellij Idea.

Comment: I assumed as much, but it wasn't clear from your question. Next, you might want to clarify what you mean by parameters as well. Does that mean request parameters? I'm just trying to help you edit and improve your question so someone can answer.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Updated question. Is this clear enough?

Comment: type completion in intellij for gsp files is just "magic".  you can ctrl-enter the var and choose "add dynamic property" and set the type there.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying this out when I found the solution for autocomplete in Idea. Using type coercion in the tag library was enough for the autocomplete. I did the below and it worked.

```
model: [user: attrs.user as User, post: attrs.post as Post]
```